# Check if webview content (html & css) is newer

Tags: android, webview, reload

Is it possible that Android Web-application could check if the content of html or css is newer?

If I change the content of the website, my Android-App (with Web-view) need a reload to see the changes (but I don't know how).

How could I handle that? With, maybe an Alert-Dialog or automatically?!

Or isn't it possible?